# Storing table in data structure with perl

Tags: regex, perl, multidimensional-array, hash, tabular

I am thinking of how to store the table below into a complex data structure, and which data structure to use. The input is a tab-separated text file, derived from Excel. Note that some cells are empty (in this case "RQ Max"). Here's the table:

```
Well    Sample Name Target Name RQ Max  Ct Mean
1   Sample 1    actin       20,514
2   Sample 1    claudin     30,544
3   Sample 1    occludin        31,183
25  Sample 1    actin       20,514
26  Sample 1    claudin     30,544
27  Sample 1    occludin        31,183
49  Sample 2    actin       20,416
50  Sample 2    claudin     25,611
51  Sample 2    occludin        27,831
73  Sample 2    actin       20,416
74  Sample 2    claudin     25,611
75  Sample 2    occludin        27,831
97  Sample 3    actin       24,213
98  Sample 3    claudin     32,065
99  Sample 3    occludin        34,556
194 H2O claudin     
195 H2O occludin        
217 H2O actin       
218 H2O claudin     
219 H2O occludin
```

and here is my code:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


# CHECK FOR CORRECT USAGE
unless (@ARGV == 1){
    die "Usage: perl $0 \"file.txt\"\n";
}

my $input = "$ARGV[0]";
#chomp ($input);

open (READ, $input) || die "Cannot open $input: $!\n";

my $line = '';
my %data;
while ($line = <READ>){
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ m/^[0-9]/i);
        $i++;
        $data{"$i"} = [ split /\t{1}/, $line ];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am at the very beginning of my program, because I am not sure which structure to use. Actually I only need three columns of the entire table, which is "Sample Name", "Target Name" and "Ct Mean". As I later want to calculate something for each Sample, it might be helpful to have these as the keys. In a hash of hashes structure, I'd like to have the Target Names as the "second keys". Could somebody push me into the right direction? I'm currently struggling with the storing of the data, as I haven't used perl for a longer period...

This is what I'd like to have in the end:

```
%data = (
            Sample 1 => {
                actin       => 20.514,
                claudin     => 30.544,
                occludin    => 31.183,
            },
            Sample 2 => {
                    actin       => 20.416,
                    claudin     => 25.611,
                    occludin    => 27.831,
                },
                ...
);
```

Comment: I apologize for the edit. Apparently SO doesn't allow tab characters in posts. There is a [workaround](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275946/3600709) to get the raw data, however.

Comment: It's unclear how the bit after the 'samples' are to be parsed?

Comment: It seems to be a case for [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

Comment: Nah. `Text::CSV` is great if you've got quoted fields and embedded linefeeds. It's overkill for simple delimters.

Answer (score 1):

So a few points - if you're reading from a file specified on command line - an easy shorthand is:

```
while ( <> ) {
```

Which has perl *either* reading STDIN *or* files specified on command line. Exactly how you'd get with sed/grep.

Second step - you can use hash slices to parse tab-separated date.

So assuming you're looking at extracting just the CT_Mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %results; 

#read header row
chomp ( my @header = split /\t/, <> ); 
#tidy up leading whitespace in the fields (there's some in your example data)
s/^\s+// for @header;
#iterate the rest of STDIN or files on command line. 
while ( <> ) {
   #remove trailing linefeed. 
   chomp;
   #tidy up leading whitespace again. 
   s/^\s+//g;

   my %row;
   #use hash slice to read key-value. 
   @row{@header} = split /\t/;
   #print for debug
   print Dumper \%row;

   #skip the H2O lines. 
   next if $row{'Sample Name'} eq 'H2O';

   #Cosmetic assignments - could rewrite to a single one
   my $sample_name = $row{'Sample Name'};
   my $ct_mean = $row{'Ct Mean'};
   my $target_name = $row{'Target Name'};

   $results{$sample_name}{$target_name} = $ct_mean; 
}

print Dumper \%results;
```

Gives you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Sample 2' => {
                          'occludin' => '27,831',
                          'actin' => '20,416',
                          'claudin' => '25,611'
                        },
          'Sample 3' => {
                          'occludin' => '34,556',
                          'actin' => '24,213',
                          'claudin' => '32,065'
                        },
          'Sample 1' => {
                          'claudin' => '30,544',
                          'occludin' => '31,183',
                          'actin' => '20,514'
                        }
        };
```

(Note - hashes are explicitly unordered)